# source database for testing optimizer

Tags: haskell, hackage

I need to test my haskell optimizer on a collection of source code, and I'm currently trying to run the optimizer on the packages tagged as `program` on hackage. However it is a pain in the neck to compile them (dependencies) and get them up running (inputs).

Are there source code databases that contain programs easy to build and run? It would be even better if they have some code that uses strictness annotation to improve performance (since that's what my optimizer does).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The suite used by GHC itself to measure its own optimization quality is called `nofib`, and is located at https://github.com/ghc/nofib

It's probably one of the best benchmark suites available for Haskell code.